# Debian server is killing my network

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a Debian 6.0 server and everything was running fine with it. This server is my environnement so I can develop web application.

Since yesterday, the server is doing something to the network and I don't know how to find the source. Everytime the server is plugged in the network, the switch and the router go crazy and the network doesn't work fast anymore. I get 2654ms when I ping Google. However, when I ping another computer I still get 1ms. This only mean that the problem is between my server and Internet. The router is so busy that he don't answer when you contact it. If I unplug my server, everything goes back to normal. If I plug it back, I can see the LED on the switch flashing crazy like it's gonna blow.

Is there a way to isolate the problem ? I have no clue at all.

Thanks you.

Comment: Is this running behind a firewall or NAT of some sort?  That may help to narrow things down.

Comment: Boot the Deb6 hardware off a livecd, and reconnect.  Do you still have problems?  If yes, then hardware/wiring is messed up.  If no then it is something running on the Deb6 box.  Login, and see what is running.

Comment: First off, cool the hyperbole - your switch is not "gonna blow". You have a problem, troubleshoot it *logically and methodically* - you already determined this system is the culprit, so now put it on an isolated network and look at the traffic it produces. Run `nettop` or similar to see if it's a specific process causing the problem. Boot off a LiveCD to rule out a hardware issue. If you determine the box is compromised proceed per http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the server has been infected and you need to reinstall it.

Comment: Is there a way to isolate the % of use of the network per process ?

Comment: Yes - see [Daniel's suggestion](http://serverfault.com/a/476464/2101) for nethogs or [voretaq7's suggestion](http://serverfault.com/questions/476448/debian-server-is-killing-my-network/476449#comment527899_476448) for nettop.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shot in the dark, but does your Debian server have an Intel 82574L ethernet controller? If yes, take a look at http://blog.krisk.org/2013/02/packets-of-death.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to identify the process which is generating all the traffic. One useful utility would be `nethogs`. Once you have identified the process, use `lsof` to see all the files opened by that program and look for any suspicious looking files, in case your server is infected.